# How to hide my surfing history

Tags: network

I am on work network, installed and am using chrome without admin rights.
how can i hide my surfing from netadmin, and if not then how can i link my home pc with work access and surf without any care? will the result be same as my work pc wherever i go online?

Comment: why would you want this? it is almost never what you want. (you want an audit trail to prove you did something that is related to your work)

Answer (score 1):

Just don't do this.

Even if you are constantly deleting all forensic artifacts related to your browser's history, your workplace probably has a web proxy or firewall with ability to track your activities on a network level (away from your computer).

Everyone has a smartphone on them they can use for their personal web browsing while at their desk.  If that screen is too small for what you need, bring a personal tablet or laptop with you to work for just that purpose, but don't connect it to a business network.  Use a guest WiFi or tether to your phone's mobile connection.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an SSH tunnel, which would encrypt your network traffic and route it through your home. The problem is that you'll likely not be able to access local network resources (fileshares, intranet, etc.) while tunneling. And while your net-admin may not know exactly what you're doing, he or she will still see that you're doing something. It may rouse more suspicion if you're sending out encrypted traffic to an unknown host.

Just because you could do something doesn't mean you should do something. Most net-admins don't snoop through people's web traffic unless your supervisors are checking if you're doing your work.